# append variables to an array from a separate file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Using PHP, but NOT using mysql(because I'm required not to by my mentor) I'm trying to create user login form where once submitted,
program will scan another file if information exists.
if user has no preceding info, they create one.

I'm trying to find a way to append these new user pass/username to an array, which will be  located in a different file from the file containing user/pass input form.

when user goes back and fill out their newly created info and logs in, 
program checks if the entered info(variables) are indeed contained inside the array.

So...I'm trying to do something like:

```
<?php
include "fileContainingArray.php";

print <<<here
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="user"/>
<input type="text" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit" name="login"/>
</form>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="newuser"/>
<input type="text" name="newpass"/>
<input type="submit" name="createnew"/>
</form>

here;

if(isset($_POST["createnew"])){

/////append newly created login info to an array w/usernames and array w/passwords
}

if(isset($_POST["login"])){

if (in_array('username', $user) && in_array('password', $password)) {
///grants access///
}
```

so the question is, is it possible, and if so how can I append new variables to an existing array from a different file?

any help would be great!!thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

An array from the other file should be readily accessible from the current file.

```
$anotherArray['index'] = $newVar;
```

OR

```
array_push($anotherArray, "index", $newVar);
```

However, I think you are trying to get a proper login/logout system working. In this case, you should set up a database, probably MySQL.
Variables are flushed when PHP session ends, so no permanent users can be created, and storing data in a 'text' file is very inefficient and can lead to problems with access etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php. You can serialize PHP objects (e.g. a User object that you could define) into a file and then unserialize it. You could build up place to store your user data like that that is not a data base. I'm not saying that's any kind of advisable for a production environment.